# Replace SATA SSD with NVMe

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata

I have a 4-year old laptop which has installed a TOSHIBA KSG60ZMV256G M.2 2280 256GB which is a SATA SSD. I want to replace it with a Western Digital Blue SN570 500GB M.2-2280 SSD which is a PCI Express 3.0 x4 NVMe. In the manual of the laptop it says the below:

Interface:
• SATA 6 Gbps
• PCIe Gen 3 x4 up to 32 Gbps
Solid-state drive (SSD): One M.2 drive
Capacity supported: Up to 512 GB

Is it possible that the NVMe will not be compatible?

Comment: Chances are low it won't be compatible

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1303299/can-you-connect-an-m-2-sata-to-an-m-2-nvme-port